# Swift Calculator works perfectly but not when preforming a fresh operation

Tags: swift

I have been spending the day today getting familiar with swift and I decided to try to build a calculator. I have the entire thing working except for one issue:

1 + 1 will return 2 to the label  (this is fine)

But when I attempt to type a new number, example 1, the string gets appended to 21 instead of clearing the label and placing a singular 1

This occurs because I wanted to add the option for the operators to keep adding ex:

1 + 1 returns 2 then the user types + 3 to get a result of 5

**The only issue is I dont know how to clear the label only when a new number is being entered after the equal sign is pressed**

Here is the code of the view controller Hopefully I do not have to think of a completely different approach.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var num1 = ""
    var num2 = ""
    var finalString = ""
    var isFirstNumber = true
    var hasFinalString = false
    var isClear = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
          // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var LBLOutput: UILabel!
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }





    @IBAction func btrNumberClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if isClear {
            LBLOutput.text = ""
            isClear = false
        }
        let currentText = LBLOutput.text!
        let textLabel = sender.titleLabel?.text
        if let text = textLabel {
            switch text {
            case "+", "x", "/", "-","%":
                if hasFinalString {
                    return
                }
                finalString = text
                isFirstNumber = false
                hasFinalString = true
                LBLOutput.text = "\(currentText) \(finalString) "
                break
            case "=":
                isFirstNumber = true
                hasFinalString = false
                isClear = true
                let result = calculate()
                LBLOutput.text = "\(result)"
                num1 = "\(result)"
                break
            default:
                if isFirstNumber {
                    num1 = "\(num1)\(text)"
                } else {
                    num2 = "\(num2)\(text)"
                }
                LBLOutput.text = "\(currentText)\(text)"
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    func calculate() -> Double {
        let firstNumber = Double(num1)!
        let secondNumber = Double(num2)!
        num1 = ""
        num2 = ""
        isClear = false
        switch finalString {
        case "+":
            return firstNumber + secondNumber
        case "-":
            return firstNumber - secondNumber
        case "x":
            return firstNumber * secondNumber
        case "/":
            return firstNumber / secondNumber
        case "%":
            return (firstNumber * 100) / secondNumber
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }

    @IBAction func clearTheLabel(_ sender: Any) {
        num1 = ""
        num2 = ""
        LBLOutput.text = "0"
        isClear = true
    }




}
```

Comment: Remark: I suggest to create an IBAction for each button instead of connecting all buttons to the same IBAction and recognize it via its text, this will be more readable and even more effective.

Answer (score 0):

Why won't this work?

```
default:
   if isFirstNumber {
       LBLOutput.text = ""
       num1 = "\(num1)\(text)"
       LBLOutput.text = num1
   } else {
       num2 = "\(num2)\(text)"
       LBLOutput.text = "\(currentText)\(text)"
   }
   break;
}
```

If isFirstNumber is true only after = is pressed then clearing then seems right. I hope I'm understanding your problem.
BTW: The Stanford course with the calculator example hooks all the buttons up to one IBAction as you've done. I think the switch statement is very clear and made for examples like this.

Comment: I will try this out right when I get home. Thankyou

Comment: This sadly did not clear the label. I thought this would work aswell.

Comment: I've edited my answer slightly. I think you need to take the `LBLOutput.text = "\(currentText)\(text)"` inside each part of the `if else` and change its value accordingly.

Comment: what do you mean by that exactly? Im sorry I do not understand

Comment: I tried the above code, the number still appears after the calculated one.         Example:  1 + 3 = 4    then i try to type a 6 and get 46 on my output

Comment: Previously `LBLOutput.text = "\(currentText)\(text)"` came outside/after the `if else` statement. So no matter what happened inside the `if else` `currentText` was always at the start of the label text. By moving that line into each separate part, you can handle both cases appropriately.

Comment: Should `num1 = "\(num1)\(text)"` be `num1 = "\(text)"`

Comment: I fixed it! i made num1 = "" at the beginning of the default for first number